# Polymorphic behaviour withou access to source code

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I want to have a clean design of multiple services handling objects of a different type in polymorphic fashion. Also, I do not have access to source code of classes which are arguments to service methods.

Lets say those classes are `Car` and `Computer`. Service `PhysicalDetailsService` would have method `calculateWeight` returning integer. For each class individually weight is calculated in different way:

```
// For car
Car car = createCar();
int weight = 0;
weight += 4 * car.tierWeight
weight += frameWeight


// For computer
Computer computer = createComputer();
int weight = 0;
weight += computer.processorWeight
weight += computer.casingWeight
weight += computer.powerBankWeight
```

Also, the price for `Car` and `Computer` can be calculated in a similar way and there would be `PriceService` with `calculatePrice` method.

How do I go about designing types of arguments for service methods, and other types in solution as well? Since I don't have access to `Car` and `Computer` classes I can't make them inherit/extend some superclass/interface like `PhysicalObject` or  `PriceHavingObject`. Should I still make such interfaces and then adapter for car and computer type? Having a bunch of `ifs` to check if an object is car or computer seems ugly. Is this place for abstract factory pattern to create different types of services? And in the end, how do I go about configuring spring bean services to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an adapter for each class:

```java
interface Physical {
  int getWeight();

  public static wrap(Object o) {
    if (o instanceOf Car car) {
      return new CarWrapper(car);
    } else if (o instanceof Computer computer) {
      return new ComputerWrapper(computer);
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(o);
    }
  }
}

class CarWrapper implements Physical {
  private final Car car;

  public CarWrapper(Car car) { this.car = car }

  public int getWeight() {
    return car.getTyreWeight() * 4 + car.getEngineWeight();
  }
}

class ComputerWrapper implements Physical{
 ...
}
```

I'm not sure what your question about Spring is.